# why two elements in the same Weyl Chamber can't be conjugate by some $g\in G$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've trouble understaning the following paragraph:

> " Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra  $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $\mathcal{O}$ be a co-adjoint orbit of $\mathfrak{g}^*$.
> Let T be a maximal torus of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}$, and let $W$ be the Weyl group associated. We make a choice of a Weyl chambers $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ in $\mathfrak{t}^*$. Let $\xi$ be the unique point in $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ such that $\mathcal{O} = G. \xi$, and let $\sigma$ be the unique open face of $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ which contains $\sigma$..."

Why there is a unique element $\xi$ in $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ such that $\mathcal{O} = G.\xi$ and why there is a unique face of $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ which contains $\sigma$ ?

Your help would be very appreciated!

Comment: This is a pretty basic property of the Weyl group. Check out the earlier chapter where root systems and the associated Weyl groups were discussed and their basic properties proven.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, I found this paragraph in the paper "Non abelian convexity by symplectic cuts" but it was given without the proof. Could you please suggest to me some reference(s) where I can find the proof ?

Comment: In the Lie algebra side [Humphreys](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387900537) is (or at least used to be) a standard. Probably there are others.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, thank you for recommending the book, it was useful!  It actually  answed my first question however It doesn't contain any informations about faces of Weyl chambers. So I'm still wondering why for example $\sigma$ doesn't lie in the intersection of some faces of the weyl chamber $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ ?

Comment: Sure, the faces of the Weyl chamber intersect non-trivially. To wit, the origin is on all those faces. The result you seem to be missing is that the stabilizer of a point inside the Weyl group is generated by the reflections stabilizing the point. IIRC this is covered in Humphreys.

Comment: Lemma B in section 10.3. seems to state exactly what I was trying to describe. In my edition of Humphreys it is on page 52.